# How to install Zotero on Fedora?

Tags: fedora, software-installation

I followed the instructions https://www.zotero.org/support/installation but I get an error message.

1. I downloaded the file into the `Downloads`-folder, then I extracted there
2. then I extracted it there.
3. then I opened a terminal in this folder
4. Then I put `zotero` into the terminal to get the following error-message:

   [username@computername:Zotero_linux-x86_64] $ zotero

   bash: zotero: command not found...

Where is the mistake? What does it mean to "run `zotero`"? Does it simply mean to type "`zotero`" into the terminal and press enter or do I need to enter something like "`install zotero`" or "`run zotero`"? Or can I use the graphical interface of Fedora for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current directory is not in the `PATH`. Try `./zotero`, that should do.

Comment: This worked. How can I make Zotero appear in my applications? When I press the windows key and search my applications for Zotero it does not appear

Comment: Read the docs you linked above, it's described there.

Comment: It's only described for Ubuntu. Do these instructions also work for Fedora?

Comment: I've checked, It works for Fedora the same way it works for Ubuntu :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a snapcraft for fedora at https://snapcraft.io/install/zotero-snap/fedora

I think that will suit your needs.

Comment: What are the advantages/disadvantages of this? Why is it not recommended by zotero? How can I check if "extraymond" is a trustworthy publisher? Or how do I know if this installs the official Zotero?

Comment: @Jakob Well if you check out who owns the domain and then you will have to read their policy documents to get a grasp of their validity. And to answer your concerns, can you trust me? What credentials do I have? Fact check is something you have to do.